# Find linear dependent rows in binary 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-algebra

I'm working on implementing gaussian elimination on ZF^2. 
So, all elements in the matrix are in range {0,1}; I have implemented gaussian elimination successfully using the [fastgauss method](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/factoring/fastgauss.pdf)

But at now I have a problem, because I don't want to use any library and I want to find all linear dependent rows in an array; can any one help me with suggesting proper algorithms for that? I'm stuck in here, because I want to find the most optimal way to do this.

Comment: what about hm, Looking at one of the libraries you don't want to use. What you say is totally self-contradicting "I want to use the optimal way" vs. "I don't want to use the library of someone who does numerical math and optimization for a living".

Live with your lack of experience and a sub-optimal solution, or use a library.

Comment: The problem is here, that my solution will be runned on university server, and before admin will install this library on computer it will take days, so sometimes is faster to write a code.

Comment: you should read about static linking. Also, you normally can just build from locally present libraries, so no need for the admins to install anything

Comment: Also, chances are, the library is already there.